# Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement twython-django

Tags: python, django, installation, pip

How should I install  `twython-django` package?

```
sudo pip install twython-django
Downloading/unpacking twython-django
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement twython-django
No distributions at all found for twython-django
Storing complete log in /home/mona/.pip/pip.log
```

I have problem installing this package following the instruction in [here.](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django)

Comment: https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django/issues/9#issuecomment-26204499

Comment: What does `/home/mona/.pip/pip.log` say?

Comment: Contact the author to make a release (since this installation instruction will not work). Or pick the code from https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminal:

```
wget https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd twython-django-master
sudo python setup.py install
```

That should do the trick.